# Is there a way to show GitHub contributions for repositories not stored on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm an intern trying to build a more attractive GitHub profile for any potential future employers. At my internship I'm working on a project where the remote repository isn't on GitHub. Ideally, any commits I make would be recorded by GitHub's nifty contribution tracker as a display of my productivity. Is there any way to inform GitHub of my contributions to this GitHub-less Git project?

Comment: Well, does your employer allow that? If yes, e.g., because it's an Open Source project, you could just create a project on GitHub, add it as a remote and regularly push to it.

Comment: Or use git-stats and attach a screenshot :) https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Why would GitHub want this? :)

See [1]

> What counts as a contribution
>
> On your profile page, certain actions count as contributions:
>
> - Committing to a repository's default branch or gh-pages branch.
> - Opening an issue.
> - Proposing a pull request.
>
> Contributions only count
>   if they were made within the past year.

and

> Note: Commits will only appear on your contributions graph if you have
>   added the email address you used for your local Git configuration to
>   your GitHub email settings. For more information, see "Why are my
>   contributions not showing up on my profile?".

[1]
https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile-page/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use my GitDummy project.

https://github.com/ebrian/gitdummy

This basically transcribes commit messages only to a dummy repo that is synced with a GitHub repo.